# How to thank an Ask Different user that saved my MacBook Pro, as well as my personal finances from destruction?

Tags: discussion, users

How can I thank a user in the Ask Different community for providing an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/121968) so exceptionally good that it saved my MacBook Pro from getting trashed?

Now, seriously, this site is great, but as much as I try to get in contact or thank the [@LangLangC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/251859/langlangc) user for his exceptional answer to my problem, I simply seem not to get anywhere because I'm too new to the site, to green to matter or too short to be taken into account, dunno which. I can't even post a darn comment on the reply to thank him/her.

The MacBook Pro GPU overheat problem was a nightmare, it prevented me from using my computer and am sure hundreds or thousands of other users too, many of which probably were not lucky enough to find [@LangLangC's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/251859/langlangc) response to the issue and possibly ended up discarding, selling or shelling their MBs.

This is probably going to be discarded too, but if anyone reads this and knows/can contact @LangLangC, please do tell that we ignored people are actually thankful for his response.

Comment: I wonder if mods could go in and mark that as the accepted answer since it doesn't look like the asker is coming back...

Comment: Somehow I wish that would be possible too, but it's not. (And it's really more honest this way: OP just didn't accept it, probably never saw it) Then the tick is not that important anyway.

Comment: More useful would be some kind of curated, accumulating 'metaQ' on main; a merger? My answer *isn't* the only one for the problem. There are other ways (discarding all kexts [like OP did], using linux for variable setting [most often seen], a boot loader.)  My answer is already excessively long and it might be unwise to include the other 2 good options as well. I cross-linked below the other options in comments in most posts touching the problem, but find that not very effective.

Comment: Moderators don't have the power of marking an answer as accepted, but a score of 58 tells much more than a single checkmark.

Comment: please do accept my apologies, I certainly did not intend to leave the answers unaccepted for so long, but being new to the platform and trying to do this from a cellphone were certainly delaying and frustrating. I'll mark the answer of my choice as accepted but wanted to also point out that it didn't let me do it from the cellphone, just as it wouldn't let me add comments, participate on chats, etc. in all cases it would pop up a message indicating I didn't have the points needed to do it, which it doesn't now that I'm trying from the restored MB... anyhow, thanks and sorry for the delay!

Comment: I think you were somehow not logged in on your phone. And there's no need to apologize, this is a Q&A site and not a chat were people expect real-time responses ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recognizing someone here is a wonderful way to thank someone when you don't have an established account and you've already used the normal channels of a positive vote for the specific post in question. This is not the first time I have seen that particular person make an excellent contribution and I've been on the receiving end of their knowledge many times. Thanks indeed to you [@LangLangC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/251859/langlangc)

The "bounty" and "reputation" system are designed to focus exclusively on the content - so once you've participated in the site to have enough reputation, putting a bounty on that specific post lets you exchange some of your "virtual internet reputation points" to call out a specifically helpful answer.

Over time, being helpful here to others is the greatest long term reward. Just like money is an invention to get away from the limitations of person to person barter, contributing positively here is how we all pay into the the goodwill of assembling a record of practical problems and potential answers so that everyone can benefit. The reputation gained allows you (and us) to help edit / curate / reward spectacularly useful posts by featuring them and promoting them on the meta site here.

Your calling that out specifically here is a ringing endorsement of the good that this group effort can deliver to someone that's not even (or not yet) a part of the community here.

Bravo and Brava to all concerned.

Answer (score 12):

I've [pinged the user in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49432510), so chances are they will now read your message.

For the general case, I'll reiterate the [advice by one of Stack Exchange's founders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17886/295232):

> If you *really* want to thank someone for a good answer, then you'll perhaps take the time to go through one of *their* questions and provide a good answer for some question *they* have.
>
> Alternately, **just "pay it forward" and answer another user's question**. That's really what it's all about.

Comment: Indeed, I have come to understand and admire the collaborative spirit of all the exceptional people that took the time to read, react and help me convey my gratitude to @LangLangC; your's specially Glorfindel as I had already tried all the options visible to me at the time and had been unsuccessful in getting them through to LangLangC.  I'll definitively try to "pay it forward" and attempt to provide useful answers/information whenever I can on this great platform. Meanwhile, thank you again for your time and kindness.

Answer (score 8):

Flattered as I am now, it is also very satisfying to read that another usable laptop was saved from its premature fate in the dumpster.

The environment would like to thank you back for 'repairing' it back into a more than halfway working condition.

And that means really all of us.

Cheers and keep hacking and sharing.

Comment: First of all let me clarify that your exceptional work on guiding people through the steps to walk around the GPU issue not only helped me restore my MB back into working status and saved it for the dumpster, the personal, emotional and financial implications of getting such a critical tool back into the world of the living go way beyond that:

Comment: 1- the clarity, detail and flawless structure of the explanations and steps allow even newbies like me to follow them almost effortlessly
2- the fact that you devoted all that time, effort and knowledge to help others just for the sake of sharing, kinda helps us desperate fellas restore a bit of faith in humanity
3- hopefully, you'll never be in a position where a MB is financially unaffordable, but trust me, that is probably the case for many people you have helped out with that guide, in my case it was basically the difference between having a PC or not outside of work.

Comment: Much more can be added for which I and I’m sure many people around the world are thankful to you, but since you’re probably bored already, let me just say that I’ll do my best to follow your example and as others have suggested, “pay it forward” trying to help others on this community whenever possible.  Thank you again and if I ever get the “points” necessary to actually use the chat tool on this thing, I’ll try to reach out to you again and gladly buy you a beer/coffee/chocolate/whatever-you-prefer through Patreon, PayPal or whatever is allowed...

Comment: Well said, far better than recycling is reuse. A+ all around and heart warming community building.